# Webmin and sshlogin

Tags: sshd, webmin

In webmin interface you can chose --> Others --> SSh login

here is the problem. The Webmin wants to login at my sshport 222 (local) i have redirected this port from outside to 22200 throught my router.

How do I change so Webmin connects to ssh 22200 instead? Because now it says:
There is no SSH server running on www.xxxxx.se port 222. ?

Comment: Did you mean the default port 22 or is it set to use port 222?  port 0 to 1023 are well known ports, tcp port 222 is  berkley rshd with spx auth. You say that "Now its says" does that mean it was working earlier? if so what changed?  Are you trying to use Port Forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

You have explanation  [here](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SSH_Server).

If you can not change trough webmin, you can change port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on host

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

At beginning of file you have

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
```

Change `22` in port you want to sshd listen for connection. Save and exit.
Restart ssh service

```
sudo service ssh restart
```